# Feature for crop select of uploaded picture for profile pic

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, profile-picture

We can now change our profile pic to a picture uploaded from our PC. Thanks for [announcing a new way to change your profile picture](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture). This feature is pretty good, but whenever we upload a picture it directly sets the whole picture as the profile picture.

Can we have feature for cropping of uploaded pictures as profile pics? Otherwise, we are required to *first* crop the picture and *then* upload it as profile picture.

Comment: *“Otherwise we are required to crop first required picture and then upload it as profile picture”* — yeah, that sounds like a horrible thing to do

Comment: @F'x: that's really horrible hence made feature request :P

Comment: what next? Filters?